# Unable to build vocab for a torchtext text classification

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, torchtext

I'm trying to prepare a custom dataset loaded from a csv file in order to use in a torchtext text binary classification problem. It's a basic dataset with news headlines and a market sentiment label assigned "positive" or "negative". I've been following some online tutorials on PyTorch to get this far but they've made some significant changes in the latest torchtext package so most of the stuff is out of date.

Below I've successfully parsed my csv file into a pandas dataframe with two columns - text headline and a label which is either 0 or 1 for positive/negative, split into a training and test dataset then wrapped them as a PyTorch dataset class:

```
train, test = train_test_split(eurusd_df, test_size=0.2)
class CustomTextDataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, text, labels):
    self.text = text
    self.labels = labels
    
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    label = self.labels.iloc[idx]
    text = self.text.iloc[idx]
    sample = {"Label": label, "Text": text}
    return sample

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.labels)
train_dataset = CustomTextDataset(train['Text'], train['Labels'])
test_dataset = CustomTextDataset(test['Text'], test['Labels'])
```

I'm now trying to build a vocabulary of tokens following this tutorial https://coderzcolumn.com/tutorials/artificial-intelligence/pytorch-simple-guide-to-text-classification and the official pytorch tutorial https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/text_sentiment_ngrams_tutorial.html .

However using the below code

```
from torchtext.data.utils import get_tokenizer
from torchtext.vocab import build_vocab_from_iterator

tokenizer = get_tokenizer('basic_english')
train_iter = train_dataset

def yield_tokens(data_iter):
    for _, text in data_iter:
        yield tokenizer(text)
        
vocab = build_vocab_from_iterator(yield_tokens(train_iter), specials=["<unk>"])
vocab.set_default_index(vocab["<unk>"])
```

yields a very small length of vocabulary, and applying the example `vocab(['here', 'is', 'an', 'example'])` on a text field taken from the original dataframe yields a list of 0s, implying the vocab is being built from the label field, containing only 0s and 1s, not the text field. Could anyone review and show me how to build the vocab targeting the text field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very small length of vocabulary is because under the hood, `build_vocab_from_iterator` uses a Counter from the Collections standard library, and more specifically its [update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update) function. This function is used in a way that assumes that what you are passing to `build_vocab_from_iterator` is **an iterable wrapping an iterable containing words/tokens**.

This means that in its current state, because strings can be iterated upon, your code will create a vocab able to encode all **letters**, not words, comprising your dataset, hence the very small vocab size.

I do not know if that is intended by Python/Pytorch devs, but because of this you need to wrap your simple iterator in a list, for example like this :

```
vocab = build_vocab_from_iterator([yield_tokens(train_iter)], specials=["<unk>"])
```

Note : If your vocab gives only zeros, it is not because it is taking from the label field, it is just returning the integer corresponding to an unknown token, since all words that are not just a character will be unknown to it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your swift response! Your answer makes sense in terms of why the vocab is only giving zeros, unfortunately when I tried your solution i got a 'TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'' arising from 'counter.update(tokens)' within the 'build_vocab_from_iterator' function.  I'm assuming I need to change what i pass to the function, but unsure how. Apologies I'm very new to using PyTorch!

Comment: Thank you for your help - you definitely pointed me to the right place to resolve the issue, turned out to be super simple as you said!

Answer (score 1):

So it turned out the issue was with the get item function in my CustomTextDataset class, it was returning a dict which was then firstly creating issues building the vocab, then when passing the iterator in a list, created a TypeError.
Thank you Callim Ethée for your answer as it definitely pointed me in the right direction!